# Ubuntu 18.04.4 suspend/hibernate not working when dual hard drives connected

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, suspend, hibernate

My system has

SSD - new Ubuntu 18.04.4

HDD - contains Old Ubuntu 18.04.4 and Windows 10

After trying out a lot of options. My latest Ubuntu suspend and hibernate fails.
While clicking "Suspend" after a few seconds Screen, Keyboard and Mouse turns off but CPU keeps running.

It's not resuming also, only option is force restart the computer.

> After removing the old HDD temporarily Suspend/Hibernate working.

So Suspend/Hibernate fails because of old HDD. How do I fix the issue while using both the hard drives?

Comment: what is your RAM size when both are connected?

Comment: RAM size is 12GB.